# php 7.4 how to expect date format "ddmmYYYY"

Tags: php, datetime

I need to force the users to enter a date like this "ddmmYYYY" e.g : 14012022

The problem I'm facing is that I can't force this format just using this :

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', '14012022');
```

For example, `DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', '212022')` for "02012022", it will not return false, although the date will still be wrong at the end.

Is there a way to force the user to pass the exact format that I expect, which is "ddmmYYYY" ?

I need 2 digits for the day, 2 digits for the month, and 4 digits for the year imperatively.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a bug to be. I'd go for the regexp instead

Comment: If there's now way to achieve this with datetime formats, using regex might be a good solution, thanks

Comment: Check that the string is 8 characters long…?

Comment: so... the risk of using string to represent dates without separator is exactly that. parsers across language may behave differently. it might be greedy for the first component (in your case the date become 21) or the latter component. the best way to avoid this ambiguity is to provide a clear separator a dash for example - so it looked like `DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '2-1-2022');`. fyi [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) is best for most use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about an addition check by converting the date back to string?

```
$inputDate = '212022';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('dmY', $inputDate);
$valid = $date && $date->format('dmY') == $inputDate;
```

Since the manual says,

> Letters that are used for parsing numbers allow a wide range of values, outside of what the logical range would be.

So string like '32132022' is valid input for `createFromFormat`, the above method will help you to avoid such date string.

Comment: This solution is optimal for this purpose.
I deleted my answer which evaluates DateTime::getLastErrors() because it doesn't recognize wrong formats like '2112022'.